# Update MySQL database using JQuery+PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to update the users name and then display a message if it was successful or not using JQuery AJAX.

This is the form in `changename.php`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <div class="form-group-sm">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-4">

            <input type="text" id="inputName" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="New name" required="">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" input-type="submit" id="submitName" style="margin-top:10px;">Update name</button>
            <div id="resultDiv"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the PHP code inside `changename.php`

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['name']))
  {
    echo 'is set';
    $postedname = $_POST['name'];
    $safename = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $postedname);

    $checkname = "SELECT * from accounts where name='$safename' LIMIT 1";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $checkname);
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($row) {
      echo 'Name is already taken!';
    } else {

      $changename = "UPDATE accounts SET name='$safename' WHERE Name='$_SESSION[username]'";
      $query = mysqli_query($con, $changename);

      if($query)
      {
        echo 'Name is changed!';
        $_SESSION['username'] = $safename;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'is not set';
  }
?>
```

The JQUERY:

```
$(function(){

$("form").submit(function() {

    var name = $('#inputName').val();

    $.post( "changename.php", 
    {
        name: name;
    }
    function(result)
    {
             $("#resultDiv").text(result);
        });
});
});
```

I have looked around and I cant seem to find a solution. Even if I type something inside the textbox, press the button, it will say 'not set' on top of the page. I have looked many videos and sources, all use some different methods etc. Sorry if this may seem noobish.

Comment: take a long hard look at `input-type="submit"` and `name: name;` and `id="inputName"`

Comment: Your form also needs a method: `method="POST"`

Comment: @Chris OP is using `$.post( "changename.php",`

Comment: $_SESSION[username] should also be $_SESSION['username']

Comment: @Fred-ii- you're right... srry

Comment: @Chris no worries ;-)

Comment: And your js needs to have event.preventDefault to stop the form posting http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: then the session thing, started? no idea. Too many things going wrong here.